# Add Advanced Open Sale module in Sugar CRM

Tags: sugarcrm, bitnami

I am using the bitnami apps on bitnami cloud hosting server, and I have installed the Sugar CRM on my server. Now I want to install the Advanced Open Sale module to Sugar CRM for invoicing. But I am unable to install that, please guide me in the right direction how to do that.

The procedure that I am following is below:

1. Login to Sugar CRM
2. Go to admin section
3. Go to Module Loader under Developer Zone
4. after browse the zip file I am going to upload that, it works but it did not show me any uploaded module in the list.

may be there is some issue with the folder permission where it saves the file or any be there is some other issue. But it did not give me any error because it stop working after some time and did not get any error message.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if increasing the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize works for you?

[http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/PHP#How_to_modified_the_allowed_size_for_uploaded_files](http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/PHP#How_to_modified_the_allowed_size_for_uploaded_files.3f)

Answer (score 0):

File permissions are a big issue in sugar crm.

follow the advice in this article to ensure you have the correct permissions.

http://www.sugarcrm.com/kb/tag/file-permissions/

I also change the setting in the config.php file

```
 'default_permissions' => array (
    'dir_mode' => 1533,
    'file_mode' => 509,
    'user' => '',
    'group' => '',
 ),
```

This seemed to work for me